# Solving a ordinary differntial equation of second order with polynomal approach

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation $6*sin(x)*y''+2*cos(x)*y = 4*cos(x)$ and I want to solve it with the ansatz: $ \sum_0^\infty a_n*x^n$.

Second derivative is: $\sum_0^\infty [(n+1)*(n+2)*a_{n+2}*x^n]$

So in the end when writing the first 3 sums ( from 0 to 2) and putting everything together I get:

$6*sin(x)*(2*a_2 + 6*a_3*x + 12*a_4*x^2+ \sum_3^\infty [(n+1)*(n+2)*a_{n+2}*x^n]+2*cos(x)*(a_1 + a_2*x + a_3*x^2+ \sum_3^\infty [a_n*x^n]) = 4*cos(x)$

Now I would like to compute the first five coefficients of the equation, but I don't know how this works...

The initial conditions are: $ y(0)=2$ ;     $y'(0)=1$

This is what I got so far (sin and cos representated by the first 2 non-zero members of their taylor-series):
[image: sorry but it would really take too long to enter this in mathJax]
I would like to get a hint how to compute the coefficients $ a_1 ... a_4$.

Note: I hope the question is understandable, math in english is still pretty new for me.

Comment: Do not use the letter $n$ for the index of the sum.

Comment: Yes, ODE is correct, index is updated.

Comment: You should write $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ as Maclaurin series too: $\sin x\sim x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!+\cdots=\sum (-1)^nx^{2n+1}/(2n+1)!$ and $\cos x\sim 1-x^2/2!+x^4/4!-\cdots=\sum (-1)^nx^{2n}/(2n)!$.

Comment: Ok, I see, I have actually done this, but I don't know how to proceed after that